# Codeigniter3 HMVC not working in NGNIX server

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have configured HMVC codeigniter as below:

```
-- admin
     index.php
      .htaccess

-- application
    -- admin
         -- login
            -- controllers
                 Login.php
            -- views
                view1
```

It is working correctly with appache server but it is not working on  ngnix server.
In ngnix server it is loading default controller but not working for

http://domain.com/admin/login

But it is working for
http://domain.com/admin/index.php/login

any help will be great helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

`.htaccess` file in your root folder.Like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Set the following configuration in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/';


$config['index_page'] = '';


$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,I try with .htaccess but NGNIX server does not taking .htaccess rule.